# Figure reference links to section

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

When using `See for example figure \ref{fig:example}.`, it outputs something like `See for example figure 2.4.1.` when the `ref` is in section 2.4.1. Why does it not link to the figure? The figure is defined like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \label{fig:example}
    \caption{Example figure.}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/example.png}
\end{figure}
```

The figure itself does get a proper label, e.g. `Figure 3: Example figure.` but the reference references and links to the chapter it's in, which is completely useless. If I intentionally break the label, for example by using `\label{example}` without `fig:`, it puts `??` instead of the section, so it apparently can resolve it.

Comment: `\label` should be placed after `\caption`, not before, otherwise you pickup the wrong `\@currentlabel` content (which is defined by the last `\refstepcounter` usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `\label` command after the `\caption` command, or even better, inside it.

```
\caption{Example figure.\label{fig:example}}
```

or

```
\caption{Example figure.}\label{fig:example}
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw the other question, of which this question is marked as a duplicate, but it has a lot more code and for some reason (maybe because I'm not native English?) I mixed up caption and section and thought it was a different issue. This took me way too long but your answer helped me fix it in 5 seconds. Thanks for the concise answer :)